# PHP sending POST request via curl error 500

Tags: php, post, curl

Send the POST request to some website API

```
function httpPost($url,$params)
{


$ch = curl_init($url); 
$contents= json_encode($params);
$access_token='**************************';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Token ' . $access_token,
  'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contents);

$output=curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
return $output;

}

$params = file_get_contents('./upload.json');
echo httpPost("https://xxxxx.com/api/v2/review/",$params);
```

but it can't send the POST request to the server.

```
 Remote Address:[::1]:80
 Request URL:http://localhost/publons/submit.php
 Request Method:GET
 Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

Why it use the GET, it should be POST ????

Comment: So the receiving server is seeing your request as a GET?

Comment: Aren't you just looking at the error generated by your script, not the one you're posting to using curl? Unless your example should read `echo httpPost("http://localhost/publons/submit.php",$params);` Not having the curl extension installed on your local server would indeed throw an error 500

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: It seems fine, you could swap out `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');` but really they do the same thing. As others have suggested. You can also try `echo curl_error($ch);` just before you close it to see if there were any errors.

Comment: @PedroLobito add error reporting, not shows any errors

Comment: @Augwa Thanks, after add echo curl_error($ch), it shows SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain.

Comment: So the error 500 was in your script you were accessing using GET, not the one you were trying to POST to, hence the GET...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to not verify the SSL certificate. If it's a development server it's fine, if it's production though this should always be verified.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```